# Pandas - check if a value exists in multiple columns for each row

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
Index  Name  ID1  ID2  ID3
    1  A     Y    Y    Y
    2  B     Y    Y        
    3  B     Y              
    4  C               Y
```

I wish to add a new column 'Multiple' to indicate those rows where there is a value Y in more than one of the columns ID1, ID2, and ID3.

```
Index  Name  ID1  ID2  ID3 Multiple
    1  A     Y    Y    Y   Y
    2  B     Y    Y        Y
    3  B     Y             N
    4  C               Y   N
```

I'd normally use `np.where` or `np.select` e.g.:

```
df['multiple'] = np.where(<More than 1 of ID1, ID2 or ID3 have a Y in>), 'Y', 'N')
```

but I can't figure out how to write the conditional. There might be a growing number of ID columns so I couldn't cover every combination as a separate condition (e.g. `(ID1 = Y and ID3 = Y) or (ID2 = Y and ID3 = Y)`. I think I perhaps want something which counts the Y values across named columns?

Outside of Pandas I would think about working with a list, appending the values for each column where Y and then see if the list had a length of greater than 1.

But I cant think how to do it within the limitations of `np.where`, `np.select` or `df.loc`.
Any pointers?

Comment: `np.where(df.filter(like='ID').eq('Y').sum(1).gt(1), 'Y', 'N')`

Comment: Try: `df.apply(lambda x: x.eq('Y')).sum(1).gt(1)`

Comment: @QuangHoang that won't work at all here.

Comment: user3483203 I'm off now to check on .eq, .sum and .gt - which I've not used before!

Comment: user3483203 - your suggestion works so is an alternative the the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using numpy to sum by row to occurrences of Y should do it:

```
df['multi'] = ['Y' if x > 1 else 'N' for x in np.sum(df.values == 'Y', 1)]
```

output:

```
      Name ID1   ID2   ID3 multi
Index                           
1        A   Y     Y     Y     Y
2        B   Y     Y  None     Y
3        B   Y  None  None     N
4        C   Y  None  None     N
```

Comment: Where in the code is it limiting to the columns ID1, ID2 and ID3 and excluding Name?

Comment: it is not, if needed then I would use a filter like suggested in the comments. so `np.sum(df.filter(like='ID').values == 'Y',1)` or if you explicitly want to exclude just `Name` you could do `np.sum(df.drop('Name', axis = 1).values == 'Y',1)`

Comment: What if there's a Name column where the value is just "Y"?

Comment: @butterflyknife that is addressed in the `drop` version of my comment

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this:

Get a list of the columns you want to check.

```
    cols = [x for x in testdf.columns if "id" in x]
```

You can use the `filter` method on DataFrame if you want for this, but I think explicitly selecting the list of columns is clearer, and you have full flexibility to change your conditions later.

After that, it's just:

```
    testdf["multiple"] = (testdf[cols]=="Y").any(axis="columns")
```

Explanation:

- `testdf[cols]` returns a DataFrame conisisting of just the columns you have selected for in the first line.
- `testdf[cols]=="Y"` returns a DataFrame populated with True or False as per the condition "==Y".
- ().any(axis="columns") scans across the columns of this DataFrame and, for each row, returns True for if any of the items in the row are True, and False otherwise.

If you really want you can change the True values to "Y" and the False values to "N".

Comment: I may be wrong, but this seems to test if *any* of the column values are 'Y'. rather than if *more than* one has a 'Y'?

Comment: Notwithstanding that, I like initially getting the list of columns - it's very readable.

Comment: @MrDave you are correct -- I had misread the question.