# Check TRUE, FALSE value in row, find matching index in another dataframe then sum values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `df = pd.DataFrame({'Question': ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3'], 'Category' : ["Problem", "Problem", "Problem"], 'ScoreTruth' : [2, 9, 3], 'ScoreFalse' :[0,0,0]} )`

```
    Question    Category    ScoreTruth  ScoreFalse
0   Q1          Problem          2          0
1   Q2          Problem          9          0
2   Q3          Problem          3          0
```

`dfTotal = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : ['person1', 'person2','person3'], "Q1": ["TRUE","TRUE","TRUE"] ,"Q2" : ["TRUE","FALSE",np.nan], "Q3": [np.nan,"FALSE",np.nan]})`

```
       Name      Q1      Q2      Q3
0     person1   TRUE    TRUE     NaN
1     person2   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
2     person3   TRUE     NaN     NaN
```

I would like two new columns for `dfTotal` based on scores in `df`

1. "Total Applicable" -> sum of all score values (TRUE/FALSE) in each `dfTotal` row (ignoring the NaN value scores) with matching values in `df` based on Q1, Q2, Q3  i.e row0 = 2+9 = 11, row1 = 2+9+3 = 14, row2 = 2
2. "Total Truth" -> the sum of all TRUE score values in a row (scores pulled from `df`)

I managed to get number 2 somewhat complete with `dfTotal['Total Truth'] = [x for x in np.sum(dfTotal.values == "TRUE", 1)]` however this doesn't take into account the "ScoreTruth" value in `df`

```
       Name      Q1      Q2      Q3      Total Truth
0     person1   TRUE    TRUE     NaN          2
1     person2   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE         1
2     person3   TRUE     NaN     NaN          1
```

How would I take into account the ScoreTruth values matching the `dfTotal "Q1", "Q2", "Q3"` columns with value "TRUE" to their respective indexes in `df` Q1, Q2, Q3 then extract these scores and sum them?

I would like an output like this

```
       Name      Q1      Q2      Q3      Total Applicable      Total Truth
0     person1   TRUE    TRUE     NaN            11                   11
1     person2   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE           14                   2
2     person3   TRUE     NaN     NaN            2                    2
```

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56739320/pandas-check-if-a-value-exists-in-multiple-columns-for-each-row) which inspired my solution but am unsure where to go from here. I've also looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57299343/pandas-divide-column-data-by-number-if-row-of-next-column-contains-certain-valu?noredirect=1&lq=1) which looks close to what I can do using `np.where()` the only difference is that I want to sum the row values not set the TRUE/FALSE values to the Score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically looking at matrix multiplication, where you want to match the questions' scores to either `'TRUE'` or non `NaN`. So:

```
scores = df.set_index('Question')['ScoreTruth']

questions = dfTotal[['Q1','Q2','Q3']]

dfTotal['Total Applicable'] = questions.notna() @ scores
dfTotal['Total Truth'] = questions.eq('TRUE') @ scores
```

Output:

```
      Name    Q1     Q2     Q3  Total Applicable  Total Truth
0  person1  TRUE   TRUE    NaN                11           11
1  person2  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE                14            2
2  person3  TRUE    NaN    NaN                 2            2
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So how would I do this if I wanted to incorporate "ScoreFalse'? Add `scoresFalse = df.set_index('Question')['ScoreFalse']` then add call `dfTotal['Total False'] = questions.eq('FALSE') @ scoresFalse` .Is there a faster way?